# Find the least integer greater than 9999 that is divisible by 3,7,13

Tags: divisibility

What is the the least integer greater than 9999 that is divisible by 3,7,13 ? Any method can be used pay attention to the Euclid algorithm?

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, some would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Find"), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: A number is divisible by 3, 7 and 13 if and only if it is divisible by ... ?

Comment: How is this related to Euclid Algorithm?

Comment: I wonder if your instructor really intended "any method"  to include "ask on MSE".

Comment: This is a question he marked extra hard and wanted us to figure out a solution by reading books or even asking people . So I am allowed to use MSE.

Comment: The question was done under Euclids algorithm so I thought it might help lab bhattacharajee

Answer (score 4):

HINT:
 As lcm $(3,7,13)=273$ and $\frac{9999}{273}\approx 36.6$

so the answer will be $273\cdot37$

Comment: This is so simple that it hurts...+1

Comment: 273.37 is not an integer so its the answer correct ?

Comment: @andrew, $273\cdot 37$ means $273*37$